# Allow only Numbers for NsTextField input in xamarin.mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I want to place a text field that only accepts numbers (0-9).
How do I restrict a NSTextfield to allow only numbers/integers?

Answer (score 6):

Create a `NSNumberFormatter` subclass and review the `partialString` received in the `IsPartialStringValid` for characters that you wish to accept or reject. Alter the `newString` to remove characters that you are not accepting.

#### NSNumberFormatter subclass:

```
class NumberOnlyFormattter : NSNumberFormatter
{
    public override bool IsPartialStringValid(string partialString, out string newString, out NSString error)
    {
        newString = partialString;
        error = new NSString("");
        if (partialString.Length == 0)
            return true;

        // you could allow use partialString.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9') if internationalization is not a concern
        if (partialString.All(char.IsDigit))
            return true;
        newString = new string(partialString.Where(char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        return false;
    }
}
```

#### Example:

```
var text = new NSTextField(new CGRect(50, 50, 100, 40));
text.Formatter = new NumberOnlyFormattter();
View.AddSubview(text);
```

re: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/numberformatter